# Django request.user is empty

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication, django-validation

Using django, I am authenticating the user through Google. I get the initial request tokens & redirect the user to google for auth. After which google redirects the user back to my website (using the redirect_url I provide).

At this point the `request.user.id` is `None` so is `request.user.username` why is this happening? I need the user ID to enter the access_tokens (that google sends me) into the DB.

Under what conditions can `request.user` object in Django be empty?

**UPDATE1:** When I get redirected back from Google with the url pattern as `http://mywebsite.com/lserv?s=goog` control comes back to my django views function, but django gives me the `request.user` object user as Anonymous user with no username or id. why?

**UPDATE2:**
all this is running on `python manage.py runserver` for now...

**UPDATE3:** Anybody faced anythn similar to this? basically, out of no reason the `user` in `request` clears out automatically & I get assigned as `Anonymous` user. All this happens between url requests from the user (from browser). Why?

Comment: Is there an app that authenticates through google? You need to provide more info on this. From your question i don't see what the google user account has to do with the django User. You need to store the google user locally and fk to the django user.

Comment: If you can access an attribute then it isn't empty.

Comment: @ignacio I can access `request.user` but it is assigned to anonymous user - `(Pdb) p request.user.__class__()
<django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x185a3d0>
(Pdb) p request.user.id
None
(Pdb) p request.user.username
''
`

Comment: why is django not maintaining the same user state when I come back from <some_auth>_service?

Comment: @pyeleven - Google auth is just an example, it could very well be some other auth service. my Q is more basic. when I get redirected back from Google with the url pattern as `http://mywebsite.com/lserv?s=goog` control comes back to my django views function, but the user is `Anonymous user` with no username ot id. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's auth mechanism has nothing to do with Google's or any other auth service.  If you want to integrate third party auth service with your Django site, you should do it youself.

If you're using [oauth2](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2) library, it's [README](https://github.com/simplegeo/python-oauth2/blob/master/README.md) has a section named "Logging into Django w/ Twitter" may help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using oauth api from google. To get the user you have to do something like this

```
from google.appengine.api import oauth

# ...
        try:
            # Get the db.User that represents the user on whose behalf the
            # consumer is making this request.
            user = oauth.get_current_user()

        except oauth.OAuthRequestError, e:
            # The request was not a valid OAuth request.
            # ...
```

Comment: hey abdul, I am not using any app or oauth api from google. I am using `oauth2` lib & have written my functions on top of this... I am actually more interested in getting the userid that Django assigned to that user...